# $\delta$-hyperbolic group is finitely presented

Tags: geometric-group-theory, gromov-hyperbolic-spaces, hyperbolic-groups

The following corollary is from *Discrete groups* by Ohshika.

> **Corollary 2.70.** Hyperbolic groups are finitely presented.

The author didn't prove it but said that 'Combining this theorem with the preceding proposition, we get the following'. Here's the theorem and proposition:

> **Proposition.** Let $G$ be a $\delta$-hyperbolic group, and suppose that $d\geq 4\delta+2$. Then the Rips complex $P_d(G)$ is contractible and locally finite.
> **Theorem.** Let $G$ be a hyperbolic group. Then $G$ acts on $P_d(G)$ properly discontinuosuly, and simplicially. Moreover, $P_d(G)$ has finite dimension, and the quotient $P_d(G)/G$ is compact.

Rips complex here is defined as follows:

> Let $X$ be a metric space, and let $d$ be a non-negative real number. The Rips complex $P_d(X)$ is a simplicial complex such that the set of vertices is equal to $X$, and $p+1$ points $x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_p$ span a $p$-simplex if and only if the diameter of $\{x_0,\ldots,x_p\}$ is less than or equal to $d$.

Now suppose there is a hyperbolic group $G$ which is not finitely presented. Then the presentation of $G$ has infinitely many relations. In particular, the length of the relations is unbounded. Let $d = 4\delta+2$ and choose a relation $r$ whose length is strictly bigger than $d$. Then we can find a simplicial sphere contained in $P_d(G)$ so that $P_d(G)$ is not contractible which contradicts the proposition.

Does my argument make sense? I mean I only used Proposition here.

Comment: Proofs are available in many other books on geometric group theory, for instance the one by Bridson and Haefliger. One way to argue is to modify the Rips complex to a CW complex with free cocompact G-action.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof by contradiction cannot possibly work because for any group and any nonempty generating set, there are infinitely many relations. For example, for any generator $g$ and any $n \ge 1$ the word $g^n g^{-n}$ is a relator. For something more substantial, if $R_1,R_2$ are relators and $w_1,w_2$ are any words, then $w_1^m R_1 w_1^{-m} w_2^n R_2 w_2^{-n}$ are relators for any $m,n \ge 1$. As for where your proof breaks down, it's last sentence *Then we can find a simplicial sphere...* does not make much sense to me.

I wouldn't bother using a proof by contradiction.

Here's a direct proof for a special case, namely when $G$ is torsion free. From that assumption, it follows that the action of $G$ on $P_d(G)$ is free. You can then apply covering space theory together with simple connectivity of $P_d(G)$ to conclude $P_d(G)/G$ is a finite complex whose fundamental group is isomorphic to $G$. Now use standard methods of algebraic topology read off a finite presentation of $G$ from $P_d(G)/G$.

Comment: The action will be free only if $G$ is torsion free. In the general case one has to do more work.